# How to use would or could in English?

Tags: modal-verbs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we  use “can”, “could”, “will”, “would”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would)

I am not a native English speaker and this would/could thing always bothers me. Please give some example + explanation on this. Sorry if the question is too naive.

Comment: I didn't notice that, but Neil's answer here is more informative

Comment: Also see [May you please explain this?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/118576/43980)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"Would" and "could" really cover different situations, although both can be used to make a request.

"Could" generally denotes:

- Possibility (either "basic" posibility on a particular occasion, or "supposed" possibility): "It could rain this afternoon", "They could be planning an attack"
- Equivalent of "can" (possibility) in the indirect speech: "He said he could come".
- To formulate a request: "Could you get the shopping for me?"

Note that "could" doesn't tend to denote a possibility that is "generally true"; in this case, "can" is used (contrast "it could rain this afternoon" with "it can rain heavily this time of year").

On the other hand, "would" generally denotes:

- The result of a condition being fulfilled: "I would spend more time with my children, but I have to work"; "it would be great if you could come"
- The notion of future-in-the-past, effectively the equivalent of "will" in indirect speech: "He said he would come"
- In the negative, to denote a refusal in the past: "He wouldn't help me" = "He didn't want to help me"; "The car wouldn't start" = "The car refused to start". But note that this is just in the negative: people don't say "*He would help me" to mean "He offered/accepted to help me".
- To formulate a request: "Would you come here a minute?"
- In slightly literary use, an equivalent of "used to": "On Saturdays, she would spend the whole day staring out of the window"

Comment: Very helpful but..  1. Could (why not Can?) you get the shopping for me? (I guess it seems like order?) 2. Would (why not will?) you come here a minute? 3. Can I use would/could in 1 & 2 interchangeably?

Comment: (1) All other things being equal, I guess "could"/"would" sound a bit politer than "can"-- though of course much depends on tone of voice and other wording. (2) You can use "will" too in this case: it sounds more insistent than "would". (3) Yes, I'd say "could"/"would" are more or less interchangeable in these types of requests.

Answer (score 2):

"If I could, I surely would..." -Aerosmith song.

*Could* refers to ability while *Would* refers to willingness. Sometimes you *can* do something, but are not *willing* to do it, for example.

Comment: The words also appear in the lyrics of a (different) Simon and Garfunkel song (El Condor Pasa) :-)