# Would and Could

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

In a formal agreement, we can place one of these two sentences:

1. He would do sth.
2. He could do sth.

What we want is that if the person, He, wants and is willing to "do sth," he is able to do that and he is not mandated to do it. Which of the above sentences is better in this case?

Comment: Also see [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/79142/109415) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5902/109415) and [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/21846/109415).

Comment: If by formal agreement you mean *legal* agreement, you should consult a legal professional. The use and definition of terms in legalese may differ from how they are used generally.

Answer (score 0):

In this sentence :

- would will be used if He is **more likely** to do this thing.
- could will be used only to express a probability, **a chance** of him doing this.

---

For what you ask, the fact that He *"want"* and *"is able to"* are pro for the ***would*** and the ***could***. *"is willing to"* is for the *would* and *"not mandated to"* for the *could*.

You have to decide which point is more important.