# May you please explain this?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs, politeness, grammatical-person

At a family dinner, my 18-year-old niece asked my sister, "May you please pass the salt?" My sister said that she was impressed with her daughter's politeness, but that that particular wording was not correct.  My niece said that she had been taught to say that (by whom she could not say, but probably by her father—the parents divorced years ago.)

Despite our best attempts, we were unable to convince her of the illogical nature of the "May you please" construction.

How would you explain it to her?

Comment: It should be "may I" and either "could you", "would you", or "might you" depending on your dialect.

Comment: There's some confusion here along several dimensions, including: (1) the various senses of _may_ (decoded by Fillmore in his famous analysis of the sentence [_May we come in?_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf)); (2) indirect requests versus _yes/no_ question forms; (3) polite versions of requests versus more polite versions of requests; and   (4) deontic ("pragmatic", as Fillmore calls it) _can_ falutes lower than deontic _may_, which results in overproduction of polite questions with _may_ used as an initial politeness marker, regardless of syntax or semantics. Logic it ain't.

Comment: If I was trying to be that polite, I'd ditch the question entirely: "It would please me were you to pass me the salt."

Comment: @KateGregory - "Might you please pass the salt?" What dialect would that be?

Comment: @John Lawler Certain aspects of your comment are above my comprehension level, as are some parts of the "May we come in" analysis, but both were interesting and enlightening as much as is possible considering my ignorance. Would you say Filmore's analysis deems my niece's utterance an indirect request or a yes/no question form? Indirect because instead of saying, "Pass me the salt, please," which she means, she is phrasing it as if she is asking the salt might be passed?

Comment: No, I **think** (from what little evidence there is, really, it's "guess") that your daughter learned a zombie rule saying something like "_May_ is more polite than _can_ in requests" and another rule defining "_Can you please_ `Verb Phrase`" as a polite request, and added them together. Most such politeness phrases are learned by rote, and accompanied by whatever zombie rules infected one's teachers, which can be anything at all.

Comment: +1 My niece, actually. Her sister said that she had been taught that as well. It seems likely it was their father who either arrived at it via the process you describe or  learned it from someone who did. He does tend to follow zombie rules in general.

Comment: @JohnLawler and others: I love the term "zombie rule", but a more polite way to refer to what's going on here is hypercorrection. Having been taught that "Can I go now?" must be rephrased as "May I please go now?", this girl concludes that "Can you pass the salt? should be "May you please ..." It's the same phenomenon as "Me and him are going" being judged inferior to "He and I are going", leading many to conclude that "This is between me and him" should be replaced by "This is between he and I."

Comment: If X Y Z is polite, and A is more polite than X, then A Y Z is surely more polite yet. Unfortunately, [politeness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politeness_theory) is not an additive phenomenon.

Comment: If your niece were to swap the modal verb *may* with the subject *you* she would get the affirmative sentence: **"You may pass the salt"**, which is bequeathing permission and would be, considering your niece's young age, extremely rude and inappropriate! :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: though still superior to "Pass me the salt fortwith, you smelly lower-class person."

Comment: Definitely an improvement, yes! :)

Comment: I have heard this usage only from young children who are still using early language acquisition logic to parse grammatical rules (i.e. *runned). For a teenager to make this mistake is learned and unchecked hypercorrection, dare I say Night of the Living Mass Media.

Comment: As a child, if I asked 'Can I leave the table please?' My Father would answer 'I've little doubt you 'can' but whether you 'may' is a different issue - you'll have to ask your Mother!' I was often confused as a child.

Comment: You're making this a lot more complicated than it seems: the pedantic distinction between 'may' and 'can' in polite requests is transmuted to polite commands, where it no longer works.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think that there is possibly confusion here between *may*, *can* and *would*.

It is possible that she once used to say expressions like:

> Can I have ...
>   Can I get ...

and was taught that it was more polite to use *may* rather than *can* in that context.

Although strictly, *can* relates to the *ability* to do something, whereas *may* concerns *permission* to do something, *can* is often used instead of *may* in constructs such as the above. That works acceptably in the first person: "Can/May I [do something]".

*Can* and *may* are also used interchangeably is expressions such as:

> You may leave now.
>   You can leave now.

Although both are intended to give permission, again - strictly - the latter relates to the ability to leave (as if the person were previously locked in!).

So *can* and *may* are often interchanged when asking or giving permission, but, in your niece's case, she was doing neither: she was *requesting* someone else to do something. In that case, *can* still works, strictly meaning "Are you able to pass the salt?" (maybe the other person couldn't reach it!), although it is really being used to mean "Would you please pass the salt?". In this case, *may* is wrong because she is not asking or giving *permission*: she is making a *request*.

So:

> *may* and *can* are used interchangeably when asking or giving *permission*.
>   *would* (or *will*) and *can* (or *could*) are used interchangeably when making a *request*.

[I was going to support this by referring to dictionary definitions, but @terdon's answer (with definitions) got posted while I was still writing mine, so I've omitted doing that.]

Comment: What about *could*?

Comment: "Would you" and "could you" border on hypercorrection of **will you**.

Comment: As a side note, *could* or *would* could nicely replace *may* in the OP's example.

Comment: @Cullub Yes, I already suggested them in the third line from the bottom of my answer!  But Q. was "How would you explain it?" - not what alternatives should be used.  It seems implicit that OP already knew what expressions should / could be used.

Comment: The first two reputable dictionaries I checked in have 'be permitted to' as non-caveated definitions. This would imply that 'Although strictly, _can_ relates to the ability to do something, whereas _may_ concerns permission to do something' is inaccurate – perhaps an example of the etymological fallacy.

Answer (score 13):

There is nothing illogical about it at all. It is just misplaced in this particular case.

*May I* is asking for *permission* while *can I* is asking whether an action is *possible*. However, as you can see in the following definitions (both come from the online Merriam Webster, [can](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can) and [may](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/may)), this distinction between *can* and *may* seems to be in the process of becoming obsolete:

> can, transitive verb 
>   1 a : know how to  
>   b : be
>   physically or mentally able to  
>   c —used to
>   indicate possibility   ; sometimes used interchangeably with may
>   d : be
>   permitted by conscience or feeling to  
>   e : be made possible or probable by circumstances to  
>   f : be inherently able or designed to 
>   g : be logically or axiologically able to <2 + 2 can
>   also be written 3 + 1> h : be enabled by law, agreement, or custom to
>
> 2 : have permission to —used interchangeably with may

> may, verbal auxiliary 
>   a archaic : have the ability to 
>   b : have permission to  : be free to  —used nearly interchangeably with can 
>   c —used to indicate possibility or probability   ; sometimes used interchangeably with can  ; sometimes used where might would be expected

This was always illustrated to me by my father with the following example, which I just found out is adapted from [*The Hickory Limb*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/28886/28886-h/28886-h.htm) :

> Mother, can I go swimming?
>
> Yes, my darling daughter;  Hang your clothes on a hickory limb.
>
> And don't go near the water.

In the example above, the daughter of an admittedly annoyingly literal mother, is asking whether she is physically able to go swimming, not if she has the permission to do so and the mother answers accordingly.

In the case of your niece, if you wanted to be pedantic, you could say that she is asking her mother whether she—her mother—has *permission* to pass the salt, while what she wanted to do is to ask her mother to please pass the salt.

Comment: Surely, the first line of your quotation should read "*can* I .." for the daughter to be "asking whether she is physically able to go swimming".

Comment: Hah, @TrevorD indeed it should. I had first quoted from memory (using _can_) and then found the actual quote that used _may_ and blindly copy pasted assuming my father was quoting directly. Apparently he wasn't.

Comment: +1 But the story is based on the song, which is at least a generation older.

Comment: @StoneyB I'll take your word for it, I had no idea of the source my father (who was born in '38) loved quoting it to me (who was born in '80), that's all I know.

Comment: Still seems illogical to me. I agree that they are becoming interchangeable in the case of using *can* in place of *may* to ask permission. And using *can you?* when one means to ask is *will you?* is also common. But using *may* in place of *can* to make a request is not. Your last paragraph describes the attempted but unsuccessful pedantry we perpetrated. Maybe that's the best/worst that could be done.

Comment: @sarah yes, absolutely, it sounds strange, not sure what you mean by _illogical_. The words are in the _process_ of becoming interchangeable but they are not quite there yet so "may you ..." is still heard as a query rather than a request. However, the sentence "May you pass me the salt" is perfectly correct if one is in fact asking about whether you are allowed to do so. It sounds strange and stilted and archaic but it is not illogical.

Comment: OK, so, she asked "My you please pass the salt." I think the *please* makes it illogical. What is that asking? If one is allowed to please pass something? What is "please passing"? It just doesn't make any sense to me. Also, I'd say it's illogical to use words that mean "Are you allowed to pass me the salt?" when you have absolutely no doubt whatsoever that the person is allowed to and all you really want to say is "Please pass me the salt."

Comment: @sarah ah, OK, I see what you mean. I agree, the _please_ makes it even stranger. I can sort of wriggle out of that by saying that the _please_ is addressed as an aside to whoever can give her mother permission to pass the salt, but that really is stretching it, you're right.

Comment: @terdon - a slightly different take: I agree that this strange construction is because of a historic difference between 'may' and 'can," but I can't agree this this difference still holds today. The OP"s problem  is their friend is using  that they're using the 1st person construct in the 2nd person.  Isn't that the issue?

Comment: @Royster I still differentiate between _can_ and _may_, personally, so it isn't completly gone yet, but I know I am a dying breed in this respect. I don't quite get what you mean about the 1st and 2nd person constructs though. 1st and 2nd person construct would be identical here: _I pass the salt_, _you pass the salt_.

Comment: @terdon - I acknowledge your right to differentiate! In the 1st person, you'd politely request, 'May I kiss the Queen,' but it falls apart if you politely command me: 'May you kiss the Queen.' That's what I mean by a 'construct' depending on the person...

Answer (score 3):

My explanation would be that when she says, "May you please pass the salt?" she is saying "Do you 'have permission' to please pass the salt?" Instead she should be saying, "Would you please pass the salt." which means, " 'Are you willing (it is at your discretion) to please pass the salt?"

Comment: 'Will', 'could', and 'can' all work. +1 for quickly honing in on the problem with the illogical phrasing, though.

Comment: This  would work with no politeness marker or with one at the start or the end of the sentence (a polite request for an answer to the question). It's impossible with medial 'please'.