# 'Could have' vs. 'Would have been able to' in a Type-III Conditional

Tags: conditionals, conditional-perfect, could, would-have-been

This type-III conditional sentence,

> “I **could not have played** volleyball when I was an elementary school
>   student if I had been short.”

should be (I think) changed to:

> “I **would not have been able to play** volleyball when I was an
>   elementary school student if I had been short.”

But why?

Following some of the advice from the [‘was able to’ vs ‘could’ question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122310/was-able-to-vs-could)
I can see that ‘**could**’ and ‘**could not**’ can be used to talk about a **general ability**, in the past. And the two sentences gleaned from the conditionals,

> “In elementary school I **could** play volleyball [because I was tall
>   enough].”
>
> “In elementary school I **couldn’t** play volleyball [because I was too
>   short].”

seem perfectly fine.

Then, the opposite, counterfactual of that first type-III conditional using ‘**could**’ seems to work:

> “I **could have played** volleyball when I was an elementary school
>   student if I had been **taller**.”

It doesn’t seem like ‘**could have played**’ needs to be replaced with ‘**would have been able to play**’, because, following the rule of talking about a **general ability** (and not a **single past occasion**), ‘**could**’ works well enough. However, with the original sentence, why do I have the intuition that ‘**could *not* have played**’ has to be ‘**would *not* have been able to play**’?

User ‘Arun’ quotes, in that ['was able to' vs 'could'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122310/was-able-to-vs-could) thread, from **Practical English Grammar** by AJ Thomson et al, that

> “the one difference between **could** and **be able to** in the past
>   affirmative is that **could** just implies that you had the general
>   freedom or permission to do something, but may not have actually done
>   or achieved it, where as **be able to** implies that you actually went
>   ahead and did it."

I feel this is an important addition to the ‘could’ vs. ‘was able to’ usage criteria, but how does this ‘actually went ahead and did it’ feature of **be able to** apply in a type-III conditional when it’s inherently hypothetical and counterfactual?

Or is there something to the **single past occasion** usage of '**was able to**' that applies in a type-III conditional?

“I wouldn’t have been able to understand the usage of ‘could’ and ‘was able to’ in a type-III conditional if I hadn’t come to english.stackexchange.com.” is something I hope I can soon say...