# "may you" or "can you"?

Tags: grammaticality

Which is correct?

> 1. **Can** you please fax me the document?
> 2. **May** you please fax me the document?

Comment: *Will* is also an option.

Comment: Also *won't*, *could*, *would*, and *might*.

Comment: May you find an answer to your question either through research, or perhaps at [ell.se].

Comment: Related: [May you please explain this?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118576/may-you-please-explain-this)

Answer (score 3):

I've often heard that one should avoid the use of "can" in a request as the word indicates the ability to do something rather than the possibility of doing something. In this case I would probably use

> **Could** you please fax me the document?

Comment: Yeah, but that's just something elementary school teachers tell children. Incidentally, [it's completely unfounded](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acan). Why we entrust the least qualified people to educate our youth I have no idea...

Comment: Yes, I think it is a bit obsessive, however, either way, I think the "could" sounds more polite.

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct. However "can" entails the issue of "possibility". If you ask someone "can you" it is as if you're wondering if they are **capable of doing it**. "May" is typically used for requests, but I will definitely side with **WindowsDude7** right above! "Could" is definitely your best shot if you want to express politeness :)

Comment: But one wouldn't use *may* in this situation. It is used when asking permission. *May you please fax me the document* is not idiomatic. *May I ask you to fax the document* would work, and would be polite enough for one to dispense with *please*.