# "when would" vs "when will"

Tags: grammar, verbs, future, will-would, future-in-past

I'm trying to ask a question about the future. So which form of the verb "will" should I use?

> So, when will it be there?
>   So, when would it be there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should we use "can", "could", "will", "would"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5902/when-should-we-use-can-could-will-would), [When should I use "Would", "Would have", "Will", and "Will have"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I use "Would",  "Would have", "Will", and "Will have"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3657/when-should-i-use-would-would-have-will-and-will-have)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just talking specifically here for their usage in the future tense:

Both are used for the future.  The difference is:

*Would* is used when the thing discussed is only *planned*, and not for sure.(subjunctive)

> When would the ball game be, if it is going to take place?

*Will* is used when the thing is already planned, and confirmed that it is going to happen.

> So, what was the time when the party will begin?

Comment: Ooh.  Subjunctive mood.

Comment: Yes, that's the term

Answer (score 3):

*Would* is used to:

- express a polite request: "Would you pass me the bottle of wine?"
- express willingness or consent: "Who would like to live there?"
- express a conjecture, opinion, or hope: "I would imagine that they'll want to stay here."

*Would* is also the past of *will*.

> The windows would not close.
>   He said he would not return for a couple of days.

*Will* in your example is used for a fact: Something will be there, and you want to know then.
If you used *would* in the sentence, you would ask an opinion or a conjecture; for example, the people to whom you ask don't know exactly, but you want their opinion, or a conjecture about when it could possibly be there.