# I will/would say that

Tags: grammar, sentence, syntactic-analysis, descriptive-grammar

What is the difference between the following sentences?

1- I will say that it is good for you.
2- I would say that it is good for you

Comment: What has your research into the meanings of *will* and *would* provided?

Comment: [kiamlaluno's answer to “when would” vs “when will”](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/37647/77227) is relevant

Comment: In the senses which perhaps correspond most closely, 'I will say that it is good for you.' has the sense that you're sticking your neck out and claiming that it is good for you (with the implication that other things you've suggested about 'it' are less certain). 'I would say that it is good for you' means that you're risking saying the same thing, but wearing neck armour this time. A more guarded / hedged assertion.

Answer (score 2):

1st sentence states possibility.
"If he asks me, I will say that it is good for him."
2nd sentence states suggestion.
"If you ask me, I would say, it is good for you."

Answer (score 0):

The first can be a prediction or a promise.
The second is delivering an opinion.